# angular material grid system

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am confused with [angular material design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) and [material css](http://materializecss.com/). 
Why do both have different layout and grids?
What is the equivalent for bootstrap container in [angular material design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/)?

Shall I use [angular material design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) for my project comparing with bootstrap?

Comment: Alaksandar, are you still confused, or do you have enough information to pick an answer. If you got useful information, thank someone with a selection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main reason to go with Angular Material is because it is based on Flexible Box Layout specification, witch is a W3C standard [Flexible Box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

The closer tag for bootstrap container could be: `<div layout="row" layout-wrap></div>`

Answer (score 10):

Angular Material Design does not have an exact equivalent to a Bootstrap container because Material Design (AMD) is more flexible. A container has 8 sections.  AMD has the layout and flex attributes. AMD's flex can increment by 5% (20 sections in BS) or by 33 and 66 (2 sections) or by combinations of 5%, 33% and 66%, which can go to more than 100% (most any number of sections) in which case multiple lines are automatically created. The best single page with examples that I've found, so far, is https://material.angularjs.org/#/layout/grid  Click on the Source box above each example to get more specifics about AMD's HTML syntax for layout and flex.

You have further flexibility via Child Alignment, which controls spacing between each div in horizontal and vertical. Click the radio buttons on that page to see how divs are centered, or spread, or pushed to one end, or lifted to the top, etc.

The HTML syntax displayed will work on a set sized page. If you want the equivalent of media-queries to change sizes for different devices, you have some further coding to do to make angular controllers.  Look at the DEMOS examples for various components to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Angular Material grid > Bootstrap grid, especially for Angular applications.  Bootstrap grid uses `float`, which is outdated compared to flexible box model.  `float` replaced the horrendous table layouts, but now flexible box model is starting to push `float` aside (for grid layouts).  Just note that you need to add certain suffixes in your CSS for older browsers. See [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) for an example of how to implement `flex` for older browsers.  Bootstrap grid applications also require you to create an endless amount of divs, which looks terrible and should be avoided in any application using HTML5.  Technically, you could write your own Angular directives to replace certain divs, and group them based on what or how they display, but then why not just use Angular Material when they have already done that for you?

Answer (score 0):

Materialize is a modern responsiveCSS framework based on Material Design by Google.

And

Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites.

So if you want new modern design i think you should go with material design. It has very nice animation too.

Comment: What is the equivalent for bootstrap container in angular material design. Can i use materialize css with angular directives.Will it work as expected.

Comment: yep.i went through it and got confused. I am looking for the answer of what is the equivalent for container in bootstrap so that the items are arranged perfectly in center

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer for the same question. I see some great comments here. Few additions as of December 2016: Bootstrap does have Flexbox support now. Check this [link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/) also check this [link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/) to make bootstrap use Flexbox by default by just changing a flag or download bootstrap-flex.css.  As far as, grid support in material goes, use a grid demo [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList), there is a material flex-layout engine which looks great (I haven't tried it yet). It is very close to bootstrap grid. Check this [link](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

Answer (score 0):

if you work with Angular, instead of using grid you should rather use flexbox, Angular provides a package for it:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

A huge advantage using it is the fact that you can use typescript public variables to the flex-layout directives (you can't do that with bootstrap). It also includes Observables for media query changes.